# How is this 2sum Algorithm O(nlogn)?

Tags: python, runtime, time-complexity

Given a list `L` and an int `c`, I have to find out if there are two elements in my list, that add up to `c` (2Sum Problem) . I came up with the following algorithm:

```
def tsum(L,c):
    a=sorted(L)
    b=sorted(L,reverse=True)
    for kleineZahl in a:
        for großeZahl in b:
            sum=kleineZahl+großeZahl
            if sum>c:
                continue
            elif sum==c:
                return(True)
            elif sum<c:
                break
return(False)
```

Now I found out that this runs in *O(n log n)*, since the sorting takes *O(n log n)* actions. The "scanning" is supposed to take *O(n)* actions. How comes?

I figured the worst case scenario would be `L=[1,1,1,1,1,c,c,c,c,c]`. How is the runtime not n/2*n/2, so *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you discuss above indeed has a time complexity of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. In fact there is no need to sort the elements first here. You can however implement a smarter one: you first sort the list and next you maintain two pointers: `left` and `right`. `right` moves from the `right` to the `left` over your list and the constraint always holds that `a[left]+a[right] >= sum`. In case you get a hit, you return `True`, if `left` passes over `right`, we know no such hit exists and we return `False`, since at most `left` and `right` perform *O(n)* steps, the time complexity is *O(n)*, but the sorting step makes it *O(n log n)*. The smarter algorithm thus is:

```
def tsum(L,c):
    a=sorted(L)
    left = 0
    right = len(L)-1
    while left < right:
        right1 = right
        while a[left]+a[right1] > c:
            right1 -= 1
        if a[left]+a[right1] == c:
            return True
        elif right1 < right:
            right = right1+1
        left += 1
return False
```

The difference is that you do not have to check from the *far*-right to a certain point in your array, you can simply start where you ended the previous iteration.

Comment: So if i already checked L[8],L[7] and L[6] with L[0], I dont need to check L[1] with them, the sum will be greater than c anyways, am I right?

Comment: @JustinP.: indeed that where you save on checks, you do not have to run from the far-right to a certain position. You can start where you ended your search the previous time saving the *O(n^2)* factor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it O(n) by removing the inner loop altogether.
I am going to rely on basic math and hashmaps (dictionaries).
Note that hashmap search is supposed to happen in constant time O(1)

The code below is written in Swift but you can translate it easily to Python. 
Note that it returns the indices of all elements whose sum is equal to 'sum':

```
func findTwoSum(_ array: [Int], sum: Int) -> [(Int, Int)] {
    var result = [(Int, Int)]()

    var diffs = Dictionary<Int, Int>()

    for i in 0..<array.count {
        let val = array[i]

        // if the number is already in the dict, we've found the pair
        // since diff + val == sum
        let diff = sum - val
        if let foundIndex = diffs[diff]  {
            result.append(contentsOf: [(foundIndex, i), (i, foundIndex)])
        } else {
            // store the value in the dict
            diffs[val] = i
        }            
    }

    return result
}
```